# Extending mouse click event - C

Tags: c, winapi

Currently I am detecting the x and y position of a mouse click, storing it in a **Point** and displaying it through the message box.

I want to be able to read if another keyboard key is being held down such as the Shift or Control button.

Looking on MSDN I found the following information:

> wParam Indicates whether various
>   virtual keys are down. This parameter
>   can be one or more of the following
>   values.
>
> MK_CONTROL The CTRL key is down.
>
> MK_MBUTTON The middle mouse button is
>   down.
>
> MK_RBUTTON The right mouse button is
>   down.
>
> MK_SHIFT The SHIFT key is down.
>
> MK_XBUTTON1 Windows 2000/XP: The first
>   X button is down.
>
> MK_XBUTTON2 Windows 2000/XP: The
>   second X button is down.

The problem I am having is I'm unsure as to how to store the results from wParam for each parameter and use them like I have to display them through the message box.

Here is my progress so far:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hMainWindow, UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 POINTS mouseXY;
 WCHAR buffer[256];

    // Act on current message
    switch(message)    
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
 case WM_LBUTTONUP:
  // Get mouse x, y
  mouseXY = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);

  // Output the co-ordinates
  swprintf(buffer, 255, L"x = %d, y = %d", mouseXY.x, mouseXY.y);
  MessageBox(0, buffer, L"Mouse Position", MB_OK);
  break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hMainWindow, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different virtual keys are ORed together in `wParam`. To check for single values, you have to AND them out (think basic bit operations).

Example:

```
swprintf(buffer, 255, L"x = %d, y = %d, Shift = %s, Ctrl = %s",
         mouseXY.x, mouseXY.y,
         wParam & MK_SHIFT ? L"yes" : L"no",
         wParam & MK_CONTROL ? L"yes" : L"no");
```

Comment: Works excellently, had to add an L just before each "yes" and "no" to get the correct output.

Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. And you're right, I forgot the Ls. I added them to my response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find out the state of the most of the buttons:

```
SHORT lshift = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT);
SHORT rshift = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT);
// etc...
```

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/30/272262.aspx) is a description of the difference between GetKeyState and GetAsyncKeyState.

You can also use [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646299%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
BYTE keyboardState[256];
GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
```